# net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH for CP after enabling compression

Tags: server, admin

Also: https://plus.google.com/111272585078935192473/posts/5qNuffv3SKp which seems to be a similar problem.

I’m with a hoster where compression for PHP scripts must be enabled in php.ini adding `zlib.output_compression = On` to it.

After restarting the front end gets compressed as exprected, but the CP breaks, throwing `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` for all resources (css, js etc.) which causes them not to be loaded. I have spoken with the hoster but they are unsure about this.

What is to do?
How can i get compression for my website without breaking the Control Panel?

Is there something i can do on my end?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Looks to be related to this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44164.  From what I can tell it was patched somewhere in the PHP 5.3 timeline.

Comment: PHP Version is 5.5.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we've just found a workaround for this in the upcoming 2.3 release. :)

Comment: Brad, sonds great! :) Let me know what the the problem is, i might not understand it but it could be interesting for my hosting company to know.

Comment: Nothing your hosting company is doing wrong, just a bug in how Craft serves CP CSS/JS when the compression is enabled.